# Packing several values into a byte buffer

Tags: c, serialization

I'm packing several values from a struct into a buffer to send them over Bluetooth.

I don't want to send the whole struct and I also don't want to deal with padding, so I'm copying just the values I need. I also don't want to use anything that requires external tooling like Protobuf.

This is what I came up with. (Shortened to 6 values, the real code has a couple more.)

```
char buf[6 + 6 + 8 + 8 + 1 + 1];
size_t len;
size_t offset = 0;

memcpy(buf + offset, &g_system_status.gps_date, len = 6); offset += len;
memcpy(buf + offset, &g_system_status.gps_time, len = 6); offset += len;
memcpy(buf + offset, &g_system_status.gps_start_time, len = 8); offset += len;
memcpy(buf + offset, &g_system_status.gps_fix_time, len = 8); offset += len;
memcpy(buf + offset, &g_system_status.modem_creg, len = 1); offset += len;
memcpy(buf + offset, &g_system_status.modem_cgreg, len = 1); offset += len;
```

To a C developer (I just dabble) is it sufficiently clear what is happening here or is there a better way?

Comment: To a C developer, this looks like a bunch of code that is out of context, it isn't even a complete function. Please (re)read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

Why 6?  Is that the sizeof the object?

```
// char buf[6 + 6 + 8 + 8 + 1 + 1];
char buf[sizeof g_system_status.gps_date + sizeof g_system_status.gps_time
    + ...];

// memcpy(buf + offset, &g_system_status.gps_date, len = 6); offset += len;
memcpy(buf + offset, &g_system_status.gps_date, 
    len = sizeof g_system_status.gps_date); offset += len;
```

**How about endian?**

When sending numbers, useful to send/receive numbers in a know endian as the sender/receiver may use different endian.

```
// memcpy(buf + offset, &g_system_status.gps_start_time, len = 8); offset += len;
int64_t t = hton64(g_system_status.gps_start_time);
memcpy(buf + offset, &t, len = sizeof t); offset += len;
```

Comment: Good idea to use `sizeof` However, the serialization format has to stay fixed, so perhaps there should also be an assertion that the `sizeof` matches expectations.

Comment: `g_system_status.gps_date` for example is 7 bytes long, 6 bytes as they come in as NMEA and a null byte because I use them as C strings in other places. I could change that of course, not a big fan of C strings anyway. Good point about endianness, my platform (ARM) is little-endian, which is rather unintuitive.

Comment: @200_success IMHO _serialization format_ best done (for integers) with `(U)intN_t` and friends.

Comment: @200_success While the answer is decent, how did you leave the question open?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Some reviews are of large amount of code.  This one is small.  Yet for OP who "dabbles" in C, looked (barely) sufficient.

Comment: [This one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277882/astronomical-calculations-in-c-for-python-bindings) needs help also.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Done.